# Struggling With Split Projections In My X Bar Tree Diagram

Tags: syntax-trees, parsing, x-bar-theory

I am trying to complete this linguistics question but I am a bit stuck. I'm not sure if I'm using the AgrNomO projections correctly. I have attached the tree diagram, and here is the question:

Draw a tree diagram of the phrase structure of the sentence **We expected them all to be surprised by the allocation of funds to those projects**, according to the norms of X-bar Theory.  Apply Predicate Shell and Split Projection (i.e. Agr Projection) analyses.

Symbols and Meanings are as follows:
**+** = Thematised
**-** = Dethematised
**wo/rd** = crossed out word

I am aware that I haven't extended certain sections such as the *P'* at the end, sorry about that just wanted to create a rough draft to upload here. Can the tree be checked if it's correct and if the split projections are properly applied? If it is incorrect, could you please explain where I have gone wrong so that I know for the exam?
[image: X bar theory tree diagram]

Comment: For those voting to close because "Questions requesting to make syntax trees are not within the scope defined in the help center.", please understand that this is not a question requesting to make syntax trees